# Change size of selected image in Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have a Gallery. I have used the android:unselectedAlpha parameter so that the center image in the Gallery is more bright. However, I would like to have this center image size to be bigger than other images. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: It would also help if the selected image is highlighted in some way. I tried doing requestFocus for the selectedView. However this is not a recommended way - and it seems buggy - and I really don't want the focus, but just highlight the image

Answer (score -1):

You could add and onClickListener to each image. When the image is clicked you could change the layout so that the image is then bigger.

Comment: onClick, i need to initiate a process related to that image. (e.g. play a related video). Even if I do this (say), when I click on some other image, on what event should I restore the current one ?